# Searching for a value in Excel between tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a function that will take a value from Column B in Sheet1 and search for a match in Column D of Sheet2 and return that value if found.

=INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!$D:$D,0))

However, I actually the function to search for a match in several columns of Sheet2 (D-Z), not just Column D.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your data?

Comment: without the "return that value if found" part.. a countif() will work just fine.. ( :  ref : https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/66396-finding-value-searching-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit overkill. Concatenating the index match should work.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$D:$D,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$E:$E,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$F:$F,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$F:$F,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$G:$G,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$G:$G,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$H:$H,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$H:$H,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$I:$I,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$I:$I,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$J:$J,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$J:$J,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$K:$K,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$K:$K,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$L:$L,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$L:$L,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$M:$M,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$M:$M,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$N:$N,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$N:$N,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$O:$O,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$O:$O,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$P:$P,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$P:$P,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$Q:$Q,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$Q:$Q,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$R:$R,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$R:$R,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$S:$S,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$S:$S,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$T:$T,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$T:$T,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$U:$U,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$U:$U,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$V:$V,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$V:$V,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$W:$W,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$W:$W,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$X:$X,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$X:$X,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$Y:$Y,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$Y:$Y,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$Z:$Z,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$Z:$Z,0)))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

idea : if column D search fails (produce error), then look in E:E. If column E match fails look in column F ... until Z.

Hope it helps. ( :

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array (CSE) formula, combines **INDEX, MATCH, MMULT & TRANSPOSE**, to find Lookup value by matching across multiple Columns.

[image]

*Formula in E27 in Sheet 1 :*

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$21:$D$24,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(Sheet2!$E$21:$G$24=D27),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Sheet2!$E$21:$G$24)^0)),0))}
```

**N.B.** Finish the Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill it down.

**How it works:**

`--(Sheet2!$E$21:$G$24=D27)`

- Generates TRUE/FALSE and `--` sign converts them into `1` & `0`.
- `MMULT` used to perform Matrix Multiplication, and the result goes into the `MATCH` function as an array, with `1` as the Lookup value.

`TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Sheet2!$E$21:$G$24)^0)`

- Where `COLUMN` is used to create a numeric array with 3 Col by 1 Row, and `TRANSPOSE` converts this array to 1 Col & 3 Rows.
- Power of Zero converts all numbers in the array to 1.
- `MATCH` returns the position of the 1st match, which corresponds to the row of the first match Row meets the Criteria.
- `Index` returns the `Area`, `Alex` belong to and so further.

*Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.*